# I am having trouble using SASS/Compass on localhost in Fedora 18

Tags: linux, fedora, ruby

I am attempting to use SASS/Compass in Fedora 18 on my localhost test server, located at: /var/www/html

Ruby/gems and compass have already been installed.

Now, I'm trying to create a test file and have compass watch a certain directory.

When I navigate to the directory I want to be in and type:

```
compass create sass-test
```

I get this:

```
Errno::EACCES on line ["247"] of /usr/share/ruby/fileutils.rb: Permission denied - /var/www/html/kba/sass-test
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

What am I missing? How can I make this work?

This works anywhere except my localhost so I tried :

```
sudo compass create sass-test
```

Then I get this:

```
sudo: compass: command not found
```

What should I do?

Comment: I solved this problem by using chmod 777. However, I'm wondering: is there any other way? I'd love to still have minimum permissions on this directory but still use it with pretty minimal effort. Ideas?

Comment: I'd place this as an answer, but it's pure speculation. My guess is that your normal user doesn't have write permissions on /var/www. Hence you need either `sudo` or some `chown` and `suexec`. Then your `sudo` is failing for a different reason: `compass` is on your search path, but not on `root`'s. Try doing `which compass` or `whereis compass` as a normal user, then something like `sudo /full/path/compass`